# Javascript function in laravel not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I added an js method to my app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

function hello()
{
    alert("hello");
}
```

Then compiled my assets and added app.js to my view:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

If i load my view at this point and look at the source i can see the link to app.js and if i open that app.js i can see my hello method in there with a lot of other stuff.

Now when i want to call my method i try to do it like this:

```
<a onclick="hello();">
```

But in my console i get an Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 24):

Laravel mix tends to compile all js assets into a nice *webpack*age, however this means that your function is not actually in the global scope because they are all wrapped in [immediately invoked function expressions (iife)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

You need:

```
window.hello = function () {
     alert("Hello");
}
```

However this generally not the best strategy, ideally you'd add an event handler in your vue.